JSON properties are null when uploading a JSON file and MultipartFile in POSTMAN
I'm trying to upload an image and an object (image title, description...) in a POST operation with POSTMAN, but I always got the message that attributes noted as not_null in the entity in backend cant' be null, so I suppose they are not received well.
Here is the url:
http://localhost:8080/user/image 
Body is form-data type and has next keys and values:
Key:imageDto(text), Value: {{jsonData}}, Content-Type: application/json
Key: file(File), Value:bugsBunny.png, Content-Type: Auto
Scripts, Pre-request:
var data = {
    id: 1,
    user: {
        email:"migue@mail.com",
        password:"migue",
        role:"USER"
    },
    petition: {
        petitionId: 1,
        petitionTitle: "Reforma educativa",
        petitionDescription: "Solicito una reforma en el sistema educativo para mejorar la calidad de la enseñanza.",
        petitionDate: "2024-04-30",
        user: {
            id: 1,
            email: "migue@mail.com",
            password: "migue",
            role: "USER"
        }
    },
    imgTitle: "Bugs Bunny eating a carrot",
    img_type: "png",
    img_description: "Bugs bunny eating a carrot standing on his feet",
    img_uploadingDate: "2024-05-03",
    img_stage: "uploaded",
    img_whyDenied: null,
    image: "base64EncodedImageString"
};

pm.variables.set("jsonData",JSON.stringify(data));

My controller in backend:
@RequestMapping(path = "/user/image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadImage(@ModelAttribute ImageDto imageDto, @RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        imageService.uploadImage(imageDto, file);
    }

I have also tried with PUT method, but it doesn't work neither
I need to bring the entity to the backend, to store it
Should I try send the requestBody as separated RequestParam?
